# MeshPhongMaterial doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a beginner in THREE.js, I want to create a sphere which I will use to create globe with texture but I'm stuck when creating MeshPhongMaterial it appears nothing. Otherwise when I'm using MeshBasicMaterial it appears,

And this is my code

```
var mainScene, camera, aspect, renderer;

mainScene = new THREE.Scene();
aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, aspect, 0.1, 100);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvasContainer");
canvasContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5,32,32),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    wireframe: true
  })
);

mainScene.add( mesh );

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function(){

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(mainScene, camera);

        }

render();
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code and should I use MeshPhongMaterial to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MeshPhongMaterial` requires scene lights.

Here is one way, but look at the three.js examples.

```
// ambient
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.1 ) );

// light
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
camera.add( light );

scene.add( camera ); // required because the camera has a child
```

three.js r.84